# probability tree diagram for PDF

Tags: probability, trees, density-function

I have these pmf for X and Y:
X=x= ( 0     1    2   3) and their corresponding probabilities are given by P(X=x)=( 0.3  0.2  0.4  0.1)

Y=y=(   0    1      2) and
P(Y=y)=( 0.4   0.2    0.4)

I want to find the Probability density functions of W=X+Y with probability tree diagram.

Comment: Those are pmfs, not pdfs. Anyway, You haven't said how X and Y depend on each other. Are they independent?

Comment: yes, they are independent

Comment: OK. Well there are a few ways to lay out the diagram. One way is to lay out the diagram for (X,Y), which would look like a root, then 4 branches for the values of X, then at each of those 3 branches for the values of Y. Then you multiply the probabilities along a path from a root to a leaf to get the probability of that leaf. That gives you the probability of each pair (x,y). The tricky thing is that the same value of X+Y can be attained with multiple pairs (x,y), so you have to add the probabilities of all such pairs up to get the pmf of X+Y.

Comment: As an example, P(X+Y=1)=P((X,Y)=(0,1))+P((X,Y)=(1,0)).

Comment: Why not just draw the diagram for (X,Y), compute the probability of each leaf, write down the value of W next to each leaf, then sum up the probabilities of each W? This is kinda the point of doing the diagram, it saves you from really having to think about it.